# regular expression - replace a word by a space

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have this line and now wants to replace not only dots and underline by a space. **Now I also would replace the word "German" (without the quotes) by a blank line**.

Can anybody help ?

`preg_replace('/\(.*?\)|\.|_/i', ' ',`

best regs

**Edit:**

```
public function parseMovieName($releasename)
        {
$cat = new Category;
if (!$cat->isMovieForeign($releasename)) 
        {
preg_match('/^(?P<name>.*)[\.\-_\( ](?P<year>19\d{2}|20\d{2})/i', $releasename, $matches);
            if (!isset($matches['year'])) 
preg_match('/^(?P<name>.*)[\.\-_ ](?:dvdrip|bdrip|brrip|bluray|hdtv|divx|xvid|proper|repack|real\.proper|sub\.?fix|sub\.?pack|ac3d|unrated|1080i|1080p|720p|810p)/i', $releasename, $matches);
            if (isset($matches['name'])) 
        {
$name = preg_replace('/\(.*?\)|\.|_/i', ' ', $matches['name']);
$year = (isset($matches['year'])) ? ' ('.$matches['year'].')' : '';
                return trim($name).$year;
            }
    }
return false;
}
```

The string is for example "movieName German 2015" but the output should be "movieName 2015" (without the quotes)

**Solved:**

Change now the line `preg_replace('/\(.*?\)|\.|_/i', ' ', $matches['name']);` to `$name = preg_replace('/\h*\bGerman\b|\([^()]*\)|[._]/', ' ', $matches['name']);`

Thanks @ Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: What line have you got? Just guessing: `str_replace('German', "\n", preg_replace('/\(.*?\)|\.|_/i', ' ', line))`

Comment: Please see my edit, that's the entire function.

Comment: Yeah, but it is not compilable. I cannot repro the issue. Thus, I can only suggest using `$name = str_replace('German', "\n", preg_replace('/\(.*?\)|\.|_/i', ' ', line))` instead of `$name = preg_replace('/\(.*?\)|\.|_/i', ' ', $matches['name']);`. If you want to reply as "it does not work" please provide your string, your expected output.

Comment: The string is for example "movieName German 2015" but the output should be "movieName 2015" (without the quotes)

Comment: Inside comments, linebreaks are removed, please add the details into the question.

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/vDTV8q), I just added `else{
 echo preg_replace('/\h*\bGerman\b/', '', $matches[0]);
}`

Comment: Ok thanks first, now I have change the line `$name = preg_replace('/\(.*?\)|\.|_/i', ' ', $matches['name']);` with `$name = preg_replace('/\h*\bGerman\b/', ' ', $matches['name']);` and the output is `movieName.2015`.
Is the possibility to combine the two lines, so that the output is `movieName 2015` ?

Comment: Try `$name = preg_replace('/\h*\bGerman\b|\([^()]*\)|[._]/', ' ', $matches['name']);` Note that `\h` matches horizontal whitespace only (no linebreaks), if you need linebreaks, use `\s`

Comment: Does that work? Shall I post?

Comment: Yes it works, thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an alternative to an alternation group, you just need to use

```
$name = preg_replace('/\h*\bGerman\b|\([^()]*\)|[._]/', ' ', $matches['name']); 
                       ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^
```

Note that `\h` matches horizontal whitespace only (no linebreaks), if you need linebreaks, use `\s`.

The `\h*\bGerman\b` matches zero or more spaces followed by a whole word "German" (as `\b` is a word boundary, no "Germanic" word will be matched).

Also, `(\.|_)` is equal to `[._]` in the result this pattern matches, but a character class `[...]` is much more efficient when matching single symbols.